# Navigation stack Re-Order/Re-Arrange Scene's at Runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, scene

I have a Navigation Controller with a `UITableViewController` that I'm allowing the user to re-order the cells.  Let's say the User ends up setting the Cells as shown in `RootViewController` (Picture Below).

As you can see `indexPath.row`:0 points to Scene 4 
`indexPath.row`:1 points to Scene 2
`indexPath.row`:2 points to Scene 3 
`indexPath.row`:3 points to Scene 7
`indexPath.row`:4 points to Scene 1

Question: Now when the User taps the Next Button on the Navigation Bar of `RootViewController`, I would like the scenes to somehow rearrange themselves and the stack becomes:

Scene 4 will appear first with Next Button that pushes Scene 2.
At Scene 2, the Next Button pushes  Scene 3.
At Scene 3, the Next Button pushes  Scene 7.
At Scene 7, the Next Button pushes  Scene 1.

And when the User hits the back button, Scenes pop in the same order: Scene1 to Scene 7 to Scene 3 to Scene 2 to Scene 4 and finally back to the `RootViewController`

I'm using Storyboard with Xcode 4.6.3.  Designing for iOS6.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Storyboard, you can always use Objective-C to do the logic.

Make use of `[self pushViewController:vc];` and `[self popViewController:vc];` ( or even `[self popToRootViewController:animated:];` ), you can arrange the view controllers in the logic you decided.

By default, `UINavigationController` will handle "return path" once you pushed the view controllers to it.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm travelling and will try this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: What do I do with the Segues created in Storyboard. i.e. Control Clicked the Next Button and dragged it over to the next VC.  Should I delete them?

Comment: Yes, delete them all. Manage segues in codes if you have dynamic flow.

Comment: So just to clarify: I keep the ViewControllers and just delete the segues connecting them to each other and manage them via code. Do I need to create any XIB files?

Comment: No, you can just leave them not connected in Storyboard.